# Joining Pyspark Dataframes Using Complex Conditional Logic (Perhaps Using a Map Instead)

Tags: python, apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Good Afternoon.

I am trying to perform a join in Pyspark that uses a complex set of conditions to produce a single value.

A minimum example of what I am trying to achieve could look like the following. Imagine a set of events that can occur at discrete times (between `t=0` and `t=40`). Each event has a set of three independent boolean properties that describe the nature of the event. There is some time-dependent value associated with the triggering of each property, contained in a lookup table. For each event, I would like to determine the sum of all the relevant values for that event.

My first dataframe, `df_1`, is a list of the events, the time at which the event occured, and had a selection of boolean properties associated with it:

```
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| EVENT_INDEX | EVENT_TIME | PROPERTY_1 | PROPERTY_2 | PROPERTY_3 |
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|   Event_1   |     13     |     1      |      0     |     1      |
|   Event_2   |     24     |     0      |      1     |     1      |
|   Event_3   |     35     |     1      |      0     |     0      |
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

The second dataframe, `df_2`, is the lookup table that describes the associated value of having a TRUE for a particular property at a particular time. Since there are many repeated values across all the time buckets, the format of this dataframe is an inclusive range of times for which the property has the specific value. The time ranges are not consistently sized and can vary wildly between different properties:

```
+------------+----------+---------------+-------+
| START_TIME | END_TIME | PROPERTY_NAME | VALUE |
+------------+----------+---------------+-------+
|      0     |    18    |  PROPERTY_1   |  0.1  |
|     19     |    40    |  PROPERTY_1   |  0.8  |
|      0     |    20    |  PROPERTY_2   |  0.7  |
|     20     |    24    |  PROPERTY_2   |  0.3  |
|     25     |    40    |  PROPERTY_2   |  0.7  |
|      0     |    40    |  PROPERTY_3   |  0.5  |
+------------+----------+---------------+-------+
```

Desired Output:
Since `Event_1` occured at time `t=13`, with `PROPERTY_1` and `PROPERTY_3` triggered, the expected sum of the values according to `df_2` should be 0.1 (from the `PROPERTY_1` 0-18 bucket) + 0.5 (from the `PROPERTY_3` 0-40 bucket) = 0.6. In the same way, `Event_2` should have a value of 0.3 (remember that bucket start/end times are inclusive, so this comes from the 20-24 bucket) + 0.5 = 0.8. Finally, `Event_3` = 0.8.

```
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------+
| EVENT_INDEX | EVENT_TIME | PROPERTY_1 | PROPERTY_2 | PROPERTY_3 | TOTAL_VALUE |
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------+
|   Event_1   |     13     |     1      |      0     |     1      |     0.6     |
|   Event_2   |     24     |     0      |      1     |     1      |     0.8     |
|   Event_3   |     35     |     1      |      0     |     0      |     0.8     |
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------+
```

For my initial test dataset, in the event dataframe `df_1` there are ~20,000 events spread over 2000 time buckets. Each event has ~44 properties and the length of the lookup table `df_2` is ~53,000. As I would like to expand this process out to significantly more data (a couple of orders of magnitude potentially), I am very interested in a parallelisable solution to this problem. For instance, I feel like summarising `df_2` as a python dictionary and broadcasting that to my executors will not be possible given the volume of data.

Since I'm trying to add a single column to each row in `df_1`, I have tried to accomplish the task using a nested map that looks similar to the following:

```
def calculate_value(df_2):
    def _calculate_value(row):
        row_dict = row.asDict()
        rolling_value = 0.0
        for property_name in [key for key in row_dict.keys() if "PROPERTY" in key]:
            additional_value = (
                df_2
                .filter(
                    (pyspark.sql.functions.col("PROPERTY_NAME") == property_name)
                    & (pyspark.sql.functions.col("START_BUCKET") <= row_dict["EVENT_TIME"])
                    & (pyspark.sql.functions.col("END_BUCKET") >= row_dict["EVENT_TIME"])
                )
                .select("VALUE")
                .collect()
            )[0][0]
            rolling_value += additional_value
        return pyspark.sql.Row(**row_dict)
    return _calculate_value
```

This code is able to perform the join on the driver (by running `calculate_value(df_2)(df_1.rdd.take(1)[0])`), however when I try to perform the parallelised map:

```
(
    df_1
    .rdd
    .map(calculate_value(df_2))
)
```

I receive a Py4JError indicating that it could not seralize the dataframe object `df_2`. This is verified elsewhere in StackOverflow, e.g. [Pyspark: PicklingError: Could not serialize object:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47249292/pyspark-picklingerror-could-not-serialize-object).

I opted to use a map rather than a join because I am adding a single column to each row in `df_1`, and given the difficulty in encoding the complex logic required to identify the correct rows in `df_2` to add up for each given event (First, check which properties fired and were TRUE in `df_1`, then select those properties in `df_2`, downselect to only the properties and values that are relevant given the event time, and then add up all the events).

I am trying to think of a way to reconfigure `df_2` in a sustainable, scalable manner to allow for a more simple join/map, but I am not sure how best to go about doing it.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your `spark version`?

Comment: Hi Mohammad, my spark version is 2.4.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`Sample DataFrames:`**

```
df1.show()
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|EVENT_INDEX|EVENT_TIME|PROPERTY_1|PROPERTY_2|PROPERTY_3|
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|    Event_1|        13|         1|         0|         1|
|    Event_2|        24|         0|         1|         1|
|    Event_3|        35|         1|         0|         0|
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+

df2.show()
+----------+--------+-------------+-----+
|START_TIME|END_TIME|PROPERTY_NAME|VALUE|
+----------+--------+-------------+-----+
|         0|      18|   PROPERTY_1|  0.1|
|        19|      40|   PROPERTY_1|  0.8|
|         0|      20|   PROPERTY_2|  0.7|
|        20|      24|   PROPERTY_2|  0.3|
|        25|      40|   PROPERTY_2|  0.7|
|         0|      40|   PROPERTY_3|  0.5|
+----------+--------+-------------+-----+
```

This works for **`Spark2.4+`** using **`DataframeAPI`**.*(very scalable as it only uses in-built functions and it is dynamic for as many property columns)*

It will work for *as many properties* as it is dynamic for them as long as the properties columns start with `'PROPERTY_'`. First I will use **`arrays_zip`** and **`array`** and **`explode`** to collapse all Property columns into rows with 2 columns using **`element_at`** to give us **`PROPERY_NAME,PROPERTY_VALUE`**. Before **`join`**, I will filter to only keep all rows where the **`PROPERY_VALUE=1`**. The join will take place on the **`range of time`** and where **`PROPERTY`**(with all collapsed rows of properties)=**`PROPERTY_NAMES`**(*of df2*). This will ensure that we only get all the rows needed for our sum. Then I perform a **`groupBy`** with **`agg`** to select all our **required columns** and to get our **total sum** as **`TOTAL_VALUE.`**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df1.withColumn("PROPERTIES",\
F.explode(F.arrays_zip(F.array([F.array(F.lit(x),F.col(x)) for x in df1.columns if x.startswith("PROPERTY_")]))))\
.select("EVENT_INDEX", "EVENT_TIME","PROPERTIES.*",\
       *[x for x in df1.columns if x.startswith("PROPERTY_")]).withColumn("PROPERTY", F.element_at("0",1))\
                                                    .withColumn("PROPERTY_VALUE", F.element_at("0",2)).drop("0")\
.filter('PROPERTY_VALUE=1').join(df2, (df1.EVENT_TIME>=df2.START_TIME) & (df1.EVENT_TIME<=df2.END_TIME)& \
(F.col("PROPERTY")==df2.PROPERTY_NAME)).groupBy("EVENT_INDEX").agg(F.first("EVENT_TIME").alias("EVENT_TIME"),\
*[F.first(x).alias(x) for x in df1.columns if x.startswith("PROPERTY_")],\
(F.sum("VALUE").alias("TOTAL_VALUE"))).orderBy("EVENT_TIME").show()

+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
|EVENT_INDEX|EVENT_TIME|PROPERTY_1|PROPERTY_2|PROPERTY_3|TOTAL_VALUE|
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
|    Event_1|        13|         1|         0|         1|        0.6|
|    Event_2|        24|         0|         1|         1|        0.8|
|    Event_3|        35|         1|         0|         0|        0.8|
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I appreciate you taking the time to teach me this new Spark functionality.

Comment: I am Glad to help!