# Pyspark PicklingError: Could not serialize object: ValueError: Cell is empty when trying to split vectors to columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

MRE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "age":[39, 50, 38, 53, 28, 37, 49, 52, 33, 22],
    "education": [' Bachelors', ' Bachelors', ' HS-grad', ' 11th', ' Bachelors', ' Masters',
                ' 9th',' HS-grad',' Masters',' Bachelors'],
    "workclass":[' State-gov', ' Self-emp-not-inc', ' Private', ' Private', ' Private', 
                 ' Private', ' Private', ' Self-emp-not-inc', ' Private', ' Self-emp-not-inc']
})

df = spark.createDataFrame(df)

num_cols = ["age"]
cat_cols = ["education"]

asmbler = [VectorAssembler(inputCols=[col], outputCol=col+"_vec", handleInvalid='skip')
           for col in num_cols]
mm_scaler = [MinMaxScaler(inputCol=col+"_vec", outputCol=col+"_mm_scaled")
          for col in num_cols]

str_indexer = [StringIndexer(inputCol=col, outputCol=col+"_si", handleInvalid="skip") for col in cat_cols]
ohe = [OneHotEncoder(inputCol=f"{col}_si", outputCol=f"{col}_ohe", dropLast=True) for col in cat_cols]

stages = asmbler + mm_scaler + str_indexer + ohe

pp_pl = Pipeline(stages=stages).fit(df)
```

pp_pl.show() looks like this:

```
+---+----------+-----------------+-------+--------------------+------------+-------------+
|age| education|        workclass|age_vec|       age_mm_scaled|education_si|education_ohe|
+---+----------+-----------------+-------+--------------------+------------+-------------+
| 39| Bachelors|        State-gov| [39.0]|[0.5483870967741935]|         0.0|(4,[0],[1.0])|
| 50| Bachelors| Self-emp-not-inc| [50.0]|[0.9032258064516129]|         0.0|(4,[0],[1.0])|
| 38|   HS-grad|          Private| [38.0]|[0.5161290322580645]|         1.0|(4,[1],[1.0])|
| 53|      11th|          Private| [53.0]|               [1.0]|         3.0|(4,[3],[1.0])|
| 28| Bachelors|          Private| [28.0]|[0.1935483870967742]|         0.0|(4,[0],[1.0])|
| 37|   Masters|          Private| [37.0]|[0.4838709677419355]|         2.0|(4,[2],[1.0])|
| 49|       9th|          Private| [49.0]|[0.8709677419354839]|         4.0|    (4,[],[])|
| 52|   HS-grad| Self-emp-not-inc| [52.0]| [0.967741935483871]|         1.0|(4,[1],[1.0])|
| 33|   Masters|          Private| [33.0]|[0.3548387096774194]|         2.0|(4,[2],[1.0])|
| 22| Bachelors| Self-emp-not-inc| [22.0]|               [0.0]|         0.0|(4,[0],[1.0])|
+---+----------+-----------------+-------+--------------------+------------+-------------+

printSchema()
>>> root
     |-- age: long (nullable = true)
     |-- education: string (nullable = true)
     |-- workclass: string (nullable = true)
     |-- age_vec: vector (nullable = true)
     |-- age_mm_scaled: vector (nullable = true)
     |-- education_si: double (nullable = false)
     |-- education_ohe: vector (nullable = true)
```

I am trying to split vector into multiple columns just like in pd.dummies. I've been following [How to split Vector into columns - using PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384347/how-to-split-vector-into-columns-using-pyspark) It did work before however suddenly it doesn't

```
def extract(row):
    return (row.education, ) + tuple(row.education_ohe.toArray())

temp = X_cat.select("education", "education_ohe")
test = temp.rdd.map(extract).toDF(["education", "education_ohe"])
```

This outputs error in the title. After some searching on SO [Pyspark: PicklingError: Could not serialize object:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47249292/pyspark-picklingerror-could-not-serialize-object), it is said that this error occur when trying to serialize dataframe object however I am just converting mapped rdd into DataFrame... Also I've tried `.collect()` instead of `.toDF` and still the same error so I am guessing error is when mapping rdd element.

There are no Null values and function works fine when I do it on one element

```
rows = temp.rdd.collect()
extract(rows[0])
```

Eventually I will expand it for all one-hot encoded columns.

Desired output:

```
age Bachelors    Hs-Grad    11th    ...  State-gov   Self-emp-not-inc  ...
 39    1            0        0               1             0
 50    1            0        0               0             1       
 38    0            1        0      ...      0             0           ...
```

Comment: I am not able to produce your df. If created as a string, `education_ohe` can be split into multiple columns. Converting it to a vector results into an empty column. If I create `data = [(Vectors.dense([8.0, 1.0, 3.0, 2.0, 5.0]),),
(Vectors.dense([2.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]),),
(Vectors.dense([4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 7.0]),)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data,["features"])` I am able to split into multiple columns too. For the benefit of time are you able and happy to add code to reproduce the table you posted?

Comment: @wwnde Yes I'll be more than happy,. I've edited MRE.

Comment: Though I `from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler` I get `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inputCol'` any way out of this?

Comment: Oh im using pyspark for transforming columns.

Comment: Thats shouldnt be a problem. What runtime are you on. I am on `9.1 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.1.2, Scala 2.12)` are you able to just give me a df constructor with the same data?

Comment: What do you mean by df contructor?

Comment: A code that recreate df without going through your transformations

Comment: Ive created it using pd.DataFrame then applied transformation to it.

Comment: Not sure, will leave to see if someone can sort it out. Thats the likely issue, whats produced maybe a pseudo vector. What I mean, it appears to pyspark as a vector but its not. When handled using legitimate pyspark methods it gives fourth empty array like objects. I say so because trying to recreate the table using Spark it throws an error indicating there are issues with the specific field. If field is created as a string and converted into vector it transforms successfully but gives empty arrays. Maybe repost question see if it will be picked up

Comment: Hey @haneulkim , did you end up resolving this? I've ran into the same exception when running map on rdd and the problem was some extra imports I did (not spark related) that somehow caused it. I'm still investigating what is the exact conflict.